# text length more than 3 string than replace rest with another string

Tags: javascript

How to replace the rest of a string more than 3 character swith another character?

ex :

```
var str = "John Doe";
```

I want output with

```
Johxxxxx
```

Comment: Removed jquery, no need for jquery, it's for DOM manipulation while this is string manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback function

```js
var str = "John Doe";

console.log(
  str.replace(/^(.{3})(.+)$/, function(_, m1, m2) {
    return m1 + // first 3 characters
      new Array(m2.length + 1).join('x'); // generate string with  length of remaining character 
  })
)
```

---

Or use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method.

```js
var str = "John Doe";

console.log(
    str.slice(0, 3) + // get first three character
    new Array(str.length > 2 ? str.length - 2 : 0).join('x') // generate string with remaining length
)
```

Comment: how to return value str??

Comment: tanks for solution